# Redirecting with apache without losing search ranking

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/how-to-change-domain-names-keep-your-rankings-in-google/

> I can discuss my experience on Apache servers and using “.htaccess”
>   files and 301 permanent redirects. With a 301 permanent redirect
>   instruction at your server level, the age, authority and reputation of
>   your old website in Google is transferred to this new web address.
>   With visitors redirected as soon as you apply the 301 redirects,
>   search engines soon notice the change of address. If you have a very
>   large and complex site, it could take a long time for Google to
>   completely forget about your old site. Upon successful implementation,
>   the new domain ranks where the old domain once ranked.

now this is good.

What I lack though, is a good example of `.htaccess` for redirection. It is, we have written a new page, and want to take the old one from the net.

Now what `.htaccess` file can get me started?

basically I look for something that contains the following example:

redirecting all requests in general from

```
www.myoldapp.com/something/a?someextra
go.myoldapp.com/something/a?someextra
myoldapp.com/something/a?someextra
```

to

```
https://www.mynewapp.com/something/a?someextra
```

furthermore it could eventually be benificial to be able to do this:

```
www.myoldapp.com/somelink1/
www.myoldapp.com/somelink2/
```

to

```
www.mynewapp.com/otherlink
```

is there some example of `.htaccess`

that can get me started with this?

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking to do 301 Redirects from old  URLs to new URLs.

As an example then for the first set of URLs:

```
Redirect 301 /something https://www.mynewapp.com/something/a?someextra
```

For the second set of URLs:

```
Redirect 301 /somelink1 http://www.mynewapp.com/otherlink
Redirect 301 /somelink2 http://www.mynewapp.com/otherlink
```

So you use 301 Redirects to provide a permanent redirect. Alternatively you can use 302, which works a temporary redirection... but 301 should be all you need :)